# MRTG installation on Ubuntu and monitoring RPI

Tags: networking, bash, permissions

I have been trying to install MRTG on Ubuntu (VMware Workstation) by following the instructions on this website: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MRTG.

However, whenever I reach this point of configuration:

```
cfgmaker snmp_community_string@ip_address_of_device_to_be_monitored > /etc/mrtg.cfg
```

which in my case is:

```
 cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126 > /etc/mrtg.cfg
```

I keep getting this response:

```
bash: /etc/mrtg.cfg: Permission denied.
```

I have tried to run this command with `sudo` and `sudo bash`, but nothing seems to solve the problem.

I managed to perform `snmpwalk` on the device I want to monitor (which is a raspberry pi with the above IP address) and see the RPI's MIB.

My goal is to get the graph of the RPI's CPU temperature, but I am really stuck at this point and cannot move forward.

*Does anyone have any clue on how to proceed?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish just that:

1. Enclose the entire command using single quotes like this:

   ```
   sudo bash -c 'cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126 > /etc/mrtg.cfg'
   ```
2. Create a script in `~/bin`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126 > /etc/mrtg.cfg
   ```

   and execute that with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo MyScript.sh
   ```
3. Run `sudo --shell` and execute:

   ```
   cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126 > /etc/mrtg.cfg
   ```

Comment: Here, take my +1 :)

Comment: Perfect! You just needed the first option to achieve perfection! Two lines and everything solved!

Answer (score 3):

The error means you don't have sufficient permission to open the file `/etc/mrtg.cfg` for writing.

In addition to the [nice answer provided by Fabby](https://askubuntu.com/a/696952/216503) to run the command in a non-interactive root owned session of `bash`, you can also use `tee`:

```
echo 'cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126' | sudo tee /etc/mrtg.cfg
```

If you want to append (may be next time), use `-a` option of `tee`:

```
echo 'cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126' | sudo tee -a /etc/mrtg.cfg
```

One caveat is that the string will be shown on terminal (STDOUT), you can disable this by:

```
echo 'cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126' | sudo tee /etc/mrtg.cfg >/dev/null
```

---

You can also do the same thing using Here Strings (`<<<`) instead of piping:

```
sudo tee /etc/mrtg.cfg <<<'cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126'
sudo tee -a /etc/mrtg.cfg <<<'cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126'
sudo tee /etc/mrtg.cfg <<<'cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126' >/dev/null
```

Comment: Hah!  I've added a few too...  Let's have a competition: I'm going to number mine... (+1)

Comment: I have already tried Fabby's answer and it works but thank you for providing me with another method :D

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use:

```
sudo su
cfgmaker public@192.168.1.126 > /etc/mrtg.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue running under sudo so I used su instead and the command ran without errors.  If you don't know your root password then you will have to change the root password first before you can run this command as root.